# Automated review failure from store - online_accounts

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

I'm trying to upload a package to the Ubuntu Software Store that uses Online Accounts. However, it keeps failing automated review with errors like:

```
No JSON object could be decoded. Value: "ERROR: accounts xml unparseable: (Document is empty, line 1, column 1) ". click-check-online-accounts

- online_accounts_account-service_name_myapp
       Could not find '<name>' tag

- online_accounts_peer_hooks_required_account-service
       Missing required hooks for 'myapp': account-application
       https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Specifications/OnlineAccountsConfinement
```

How can I get my package to pass the automated review?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the error messages one at a time:

```
No JSON object could be decoded. Value: "ERROR: accounts xml unparseable: (Document is empty, line 1, column 1) ". click-check-online-accounts
```

This means one of a couple of things:

- That you have specified one of the online-accounts manifests (`account-service`, `account-application`) in the `hooks` section of your package manifest (`manifest.json`) but provided an empty value.
- That you have specified one of the online-accounts manifests (`account-service`, `account-application`) in the `hooks` section of your package manifest (`manifest.json`) but provided a value pointing to a non-existent file.
- That you have specified one of the online-accounts manifests (`account-service`, `account-application`) in the `hooks` section of your package manifest (`manifest.json`) but provided a value pointing to an empty file.
- That you have specified one of the online-accounts manifests (`account-service`, `account-application`) in the `hooks` section of your package manifest (`manifest.json`) but provided a value pointing to a file which does not contain valid XML.

You need to ensure that:

- You provide a valid value for the `account-service` and `account-application` hooks, that points to the appropriate file relative to the root of your package.
- The files contain valid XML.

See the [Online Accounts Developer Guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/platform/guides/online-accounts-developer-guide/) for information on what each file should contain.

```
- online_accounts_account-service_name_myapp
       Could not find '<name>' tag
```

The file you specified with the `account-service` hook contained valid XML, but did not contain a `<name>` element within the top-level `<service>` element.

```
- online_accounts_peer_hooks_required_account-service
       Missing required hooks for 'myapp': account-application
       https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Specifications/OnlineAccountsConfinement
```

You have specified an `account-service` hook, but not a corresponding `account-application` hook in your package manifest. As well as the link provided, the [Online Accounts Developer Guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/platform/guides/online-accounts-developer-guide/) has more information.